# Ecto run where on associations

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Im running a query like this:

```
query = from q in MY.Model, preload: [:accoc], where: q.accoc_field in [10, 11]
Repo.all(query)
```

This gives me error:

```
** (Ecto.QueryError) iex:32: field `accoc_field` in `where` does not exist in schema MY.Model in query:
```

So, basically I am trying to write a query like:

```
select * from my_model m join assoc a on m.assoc_id = a.id where a.assoc_field in (10, 11)
```

I know I can write the above query using joins in Ecto, but how do I do it when using preload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope that the best solution here will be following SQL code strait forward.

We need to join another table, so we need to call [Ecto.Query.join/5](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#join/5) function, instead of preload.

For example, lets assume we need to retrieve Users, who's created posts with specific sections:

```
from u in User,
join: p in assoc(u, :posts),
where: p.section in ["elixir", "phoenix"],
select: u
```

After [Repo.all](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:all/2) for this query, we'll get list of needed users.
Here, if we want to **populate** users with posts - we can call [Repo.preload](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/3)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Virvil, as mentioned in my question, I do not want to use join with straight forward query. The reason being, I want to use the associations defined in my Model's database schema.

Comment: Yep, this is how you doing it. Simple type `join` instead of `preload`. And pay attention, that we have 2 _variables_ - `u` and `p`, so we can choose who's fields to compare in `where`